# What is the best way to stop running tasks in threadpoolexecutor?

Tags: android, threadpoolexecutor

I am implementing Java ThreadPoolExecutor in Android. I am required to stop and remove running tasks from my pool.

I have implemented this by using submit(Runnable) and Future.cancel() methods.

The code for submitting tasks is below:

```
public Future<?> submitTask(Runnable runnableTask) throws CustomException {
    if (runnableTask == null) {
        throw new CustomException("Null RunnableTask.");
    }
    Future<?> future = threadPoolExecutor.submit(runnableTask);
    return future;
}
```

The Future returned by submit() is passed to method below.
The code for cancelling tasks is below:

```
public void cancelRunningTask(Future<?> future) throws CustomException {
    if (future == null) {
        throw new CustomException("Null Future<?>.");
    }
    if (!(future.isDone() || future.isCancelled())) {
        if (future.cancel(true))
            MyLogger.d(this, "Running task cancelled.");
        else
            MyLogger.d(this, "Running task cannot be cancelled.");
    }
}
```

**Problem :** The tasks are not actually cancelled. Please let me know where I am wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your task is not cancelled just because it's already finished ?

Comment: @NitroG42 : Yes I am damn sure about it!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) regarding the Future task. From that what I understand is, if the execution started, we cannot cancel it. Then what we can do to get the effect of cancelling is to interrupt the thread which is running the Future task

```
mayInterruptIfRunning - true
```

Inside your runnable, at different places, you need to check whether the thread is Interrupted and return if interrupted and by that way only we can cancel it.

```
Thread.isInterrupted()
```

Sample :

```
private Runnable ExecutorRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Before coming to this run method only, the cancel method has
        // direct grip. like if cancelled, it will avoid calling the run
        // method.

        // Do some Operation...

        // Checking for thread interruption
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            // Means you have called Cancel with true. So either raise an
            // exception or simple return.
        }

        // Do some Operation...

        // Again Checking for thread interruption
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            // Means you have called Cancel with true. So either raise an
            // exception or simple return.
        }

        // Similarly you need to check for interruption status at various
        // points

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. But then what is the use of Future.cancel() method?

Comment: From Android API docs: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

Comment: Whenever you submit a new task to the ThreadPool Executor, it is actually going to an internal QUEUE if there is no free thread to execute the task. So if your cancel call is before the task's execution start, it will get cancelled.

Comment: But I know the task has been started executing and then I want to stop it. If you reffer to the android docs link above, it is mentioned over there about cancel(true).

Comment: Already mentioned "mayInterruptIfRunning - true". But this code only makes the thread's interrupted status to true. So inside our runnable, we need to check whether the Thread is interrupted and do accordingly. For eg: Suppose if you are doing some IO operation inside your runnable code and if you call the cancel method with true, the thread interrupted status will be set and inside the IO handling code of android, they were checking is interrupted and if its true they are raising ThreadInterrupted Exception. In our normal code also, we need to do the same else no use of "cancel(true)"

Comment: Thank you so much for making this clear. I am accepting your answer. I don't have the required reputation else I would have voted up your answer :).